# Видимость function declaration

Tags: javascript

Функция объявленная как "function declaration" создаётся еще до выполнения кода, на стадии инициализации. Это относится и к функциям в глобальном объекте и к функциям внутри блоков(также других функций). Но между функцией в блоке и в глобальном объекте - естественно разная область видимости. И функция 'welcome', не выполнится снаружи 'if'. Но т.к она вида "function declaration" - всё равно создаётся до выполнения кода. И если ей вызвать до объявления функции (но внутри if), она выполняется.

Это верные утверждения? Т.е function declaration, создаются всегда ДО выполнения функции, вне зависимости от своего местоположения ?

```
if (age < 18) {
      welcome()
      function welcome() {
            alert("Привет!");
      }
} else {
      welcome()
      function welcome() {
            alert("Здравствуйте!");
      }
}
```

Comment: `if( false ){ function welcome(){ alert('ok'); } } welcome();` → Uncaught TypeError: welcome is not a function )

Comment: Тут всё расписано https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME у вас es2015. В легаси сработает, в строгом режиме до es2015 упадёт на объявлении функции